Determining the material properties for alloys
I have the individual material speed of sound and Hugoniot s-parameters for different metals, and I wish to determine the same for an alloy with a specific ratio of each metal in it. Does taking the weighted average suffice?

Maybe, maybe not. Is the alloy the same phase? Is the alloy multiple phases? How different are the melting points of the constituents? Etc etc etc…

@JonCuster The alloy consists of Iron, Aluminum, and Copper. Does this information help?

That could get ugly fast. The Al-Cu binary diagram shows 11 intermediate phases. The Cu-Fe diagram shows no intermediate phases and limited mutual solubility. The Al-Fe diagram has 4 intermediate phases, the magnetic transition in the bcc Fe phase, and two ordered phases, with the B2 ordered bcc phase taking up a chunk of the diagram. A paper covering the Al-rich portion of the ternary Al-Cu-Fe diagram is Hai-Lin Chen, et al., J. Mater. Res., Vol. 24, No. 10, Oct 2009.
